passing cell value through as filter
I have the below but where the filter is set to "Alabama", I would like that filter to be tied to a cell value where the user can change the location from a drop down and the table refresh. Is that possible?
here is what I tried:

    DEFINE
    VAR __DS0FilterTable =
    TREATAS({"Alabama"}, 'Organization'[OpCo])

      VAR __DS0Core =
      SELECTCOLUMNS(
      KEEPFILTERS(
      FILTER(
     KEEPFILTERS(
     SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
     'Organization'[OpCo],
    'Clients'[Client Code],
    'Clients'[Name],
    __DS0FilterTable,
     "CountRowsFactPolicy", COUNTROWS('FactPolicy')
    )
    ),
    OR(
    OR(
NOT(ISBLANK('Organization'[OpCo])),
NOT(ISBLANK('Clients'[Client Code]))
),
NOT(ISBLANK('Clients'[Name]))
)
)
),
"'Organization'[OpCo]", 'Organization'[OpCo],
"'Clients'[Client Code]", 'Clients'[Client Code],
"'Clients'[Name]", 'Clients'[Name]
)

VAR __DS0BodyLimited =
TOPN(500000, __DS0Core, 'Organization'[OpCo], 1, 'Clients'[Client Code], 1, 'Clients'[Name], 1)

EVALUATE
__DS0BodyLimited

ORDER BY
'Organization'[OpCo], 'Clients'[Client Code], 'Clients'[Name]
Quote ReplyReport


no, it's not possible. Calculated tables can not respond to user actions. You need to use measures, without building new tables.

Thank you for the response.    Is there an article you can point me to that might help me accomplish this?

I'd recommend to post a new question; show your data model, provide data sample (or mocked-up pbix), and describe the desired outcome. You are more likely to get good help.

sounds great.   I did that this morning
